# Magento1.9: How to add video in product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

How to add product video to product detailed page?

We want to show that video based on creating new attribute then want to show that there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create one attribute under admin panel > catalog > attributes > create the attribute on the name of the video
2. By using , you can get that data

> ```
> <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="<?php echo $_product-> 
>  getData('video'); ?>" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```

3. You have to use this code at your view.phtml file.